# How to combine contents of two files having the same value in a column?

Tags: text-processing, columns, join

File1:

```
00:00 274
00:04 476
00:05 450
00:06 499
00:07 373
00:08 206
00:09 471
00:10 154
```

File2:

```
00:00 183
00:01 60
00:02 344
00:03 540
00:04 450
00:07 348
00:09 473
00:10 203
```

Desired output:

```
00:00,274,183
00:01,0,60
00:02,0,344
00:03,0,540
00:04,476,450
00:05,450,0
00:06,499,0
00:07,373,348
00:08,206,0
00:09,471,473
00:10,154,203
```

Column 1 of each file will be checked and if same, values will be joined to the output. Please note the "0" value for those contents not present on either file. Also, this will be used for combining contents of 6 files.

Comment: file1, file2 and output is arranged in columns e.g. Column1 is Time and Column2 is Count. For output, Column1 is Time Column 2 and 3 are values from file1 and file2. Not sure why it was displayed like that.

Comment: try listing the contents of file1 and file2 as code.

Comment: Did you try `join`?

Comment: you swapped values for 00:02 and 00:03, see my answer

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input files are alphabetically sorted on their join field (as they are in your sample):

```
join -e0 -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 file1 file2 | tr ' ' ,
```

Comment: `|tr ' ' ','` to be more precise

Answer (score 3):

**Bash**

```
#!/bin/bash 
file1=t1
file2=t2
while  read line
do
        v1=$(grep "${line}" $file1|| echo 0)
        v2=$(grep "${line}" $file2|| echo 0)
        echo ${line},${v1#* },${v2#* }

done < <(awk '!a[$1]++{print $1| "sort"}' $file1 $file2)
```

**Output**

```
00:00,274,183
00:01,0,60
00:02,0,344
00:03,0,540
00:04,476,450
00:05,450,0
00:06,499,0
00:07,373,348
00:08,206,0
00:09,471,473
00:10,154,203
```

Comment: ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 10: `done < ( awk '!a[$1]++{print $1| "sort"}' $file1 $file2 )'

Comment: `awk '!a[$1]++{print $1| "sort"}' 1.txt 2.txt |  sh -c 'while read LINE; do v1=$(grep "${LINE}" 1.
txt || echo 0);v2=$(grep "${LINE}" 2.txt|| echo 0);echo ${LINE},${v1#* },${v2#* };done'`

Comment: I could not get yours to work. The awk command kept causing syntax errors. I posted a turned around version that pipes to sh and it works. I really like your solution. I was not aware of the parameter expansion to remove prefixes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `join` does not add the files that are missing lines. It's `-e` option only does add the argument to lines with the key. You can  extract the keys, add them to each file if not there yet with standard tools and then use join, but by then you are better of writing a small program, for example in Python:

```python
import sys

default = ['0'] * len(sys.argv[1:])
r = {}
for idx, fn in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
    for line in open(fn):
        c1, c2 = line.split()
        r.setdefault(c1, default[:])[idx] = c2
for c1 in sorted(r): # print output
    print("{},{}".format(c1, ','.join(r[c1])))
```

save as `join.py` and run with

```
python join.py file1 file2 [file3 ....]
```

i.e. you can add as many files as you have on the commandline

This gives **exactly** the output you requested (except that you swapped values for 00:02 and 00:03)

Comment: Yes, [`join` does work in this case](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111299/22565), you want the `-a` option.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the lines is not important, or you don't mind to have the input and output sorted (which doesn't seem to pose a problem considering the input you have given), you can use `join` twice:

```
(
    join -a 1 -e "0" -o "1.1 1.2 2.2" file1 file2
    join -a 2 -e "0" -o "2.1 1.2 2.2" file1 file2
) | sort -u | sed "s/ /,/g"
```

The `-a` option reproduces unmatched lines from the first (`-a1`) or the second (`-a2`) file, `-e "0"` uses zero as a substitute for the missing lines from the other file, `-o` describes the format of the output lines as a list of FILE.FIELD values (see `join(1)` man page). `sort -u` removes duplicates of lines. The final `sed` replaces *all* spaces on each line with commas.

Or, if you are adventurous enough, you'll find out that [once](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111299/22886) is enough with the right options. Thanks Stephane!

Comment: Wow. I like this one. Haven't used join in such a fashion before.

Comment: You don't need the two join invocations, [you can use `-o 0` to output the join key](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111299/22565)

Comment: @rking no wonder - given Stephane's answer it is a rather silly solution. :)

Comment: It wasn't apparent from reading the man that you could combine both -a 1 and -a 2 in one join. Makes sense now!

Comment: @rking Exactly my point - the man page could use some improvements indeed.

Answer (score 2):

### Edited

Simpler version.

#### Updated Script: test2.awk

```
FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$2;next; }
{ 
    if ($1 in a){ 
        a[$1] = ( $1 "," a[$1] "," $2 )
    }else{
        a[$1] = ( $1 ",0," $2 )
    }
} END {
    for ( x in a ){
        if ( match(a[x],x) ){print a[x]}else{ print x "," a[x] ",0"}
    }
}
```

#### Commandline

```
awk -f new.awk 1.txt 2.txt | sort
```

#### Original First Attempt

Here is a go with awk. Not sure how to quickly sort an associative array so just pipe it to sort. Works.

#### test.awk script

```
BEGIN{st=0}
{if(st==0){
    cur=FILENAME; st++} 
 if((st==1)&&(cur==FILENAME)){ 
     a[$1]=$2; 
 }
 else{ b[$1]=$2 } 
}END{ 
    for(i in b){ 
        if(a[i]){ 
            a[i]=a[i] "," b[i]; 
        }else{ a[i]="0," b[i] } }
    for(i in a){ 
        if (b[i]){
            print i "," a[i] 
        }else{ 
            print i "," a[i] ",0" 
        }
    }
}
```

#### cmdline

```
awk -f test.awk 1.txt 2.txt | sort
```

#### output

```
00:00,274,183
00:01,0,60
00:02,0,344
00:03,0,540
00:04,476,450
00:05,450,0
00:06,499,0
00:07,373,348
00:08,206,0
00:09,471,473
00:10,154,203
```

Comment: have you test this script ?? it's not giving desire output..

Comment: Yes, I just copy pasted again and it gave the results as shown. What results are you getting?

Comment: hmm, it's working now..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Perl script

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$filenum = $#ARGV;
if ($filenum < 0) {
    print "No arguments\n";
    exit(1);
}

for (my $i=0; $i<=$filenum; $i++) {
    open($fh,"<","$ARGV[$i]") || die "Could not open $ARGV[$i]\n";

    while (<$fh>) {
        ($a,$b) = split/\s/;
        @{$myhash{$a}}[$i]=$b;
    }
    close($fh);
}

foreach my $x ( sort keys %myhash) {
    print "$x";
    for (my $i=0; $i<=$filenum; $i++) {
        if (defined @{$myhash{$x}}[$i]) {
            print ",@{$myhash{$x}}[$i]";
        }
        else {
            print ",0";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

save it to a `myscript.pl` file and run it as:

```
perl myscript.pl file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: This does not get the output in the requested order, but even if you add `| sort` the `00:01` line reads `00:01,60,0` and not `00:01,0,60` as requested

Comment: @Timo: Initially the desired output was hard to read. The request was to have 0 if the value is not in one of the files, but not necessarily ordered.